# The methods in Netbeans are always italic. How to remove italic?

Tags: netbeans, ide

The methods in Netbeans are always italic and bold. I can unbold them without any problems, but i can't unitalic them. How can it be done? I tried to change the style to normal, but it just doesn't remove the italic.

Comment: Did you go to Tools -> Options -> Fonts and Colors -> Method -> Font -> PLain?

Comment: it might just be that the **static** methods are in italics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What language are you using? For java make sure to set static method calls to plain aswell.

go to Tools -> Options -> Fonts and Color

Choose language

Change method and static element font to plain.